# Cannot convert pandas column from string to int

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, int

The below column in data frame needs to be converted to int:

```
dsAttendEnroll.District.head()

0    DISTRICT 01
1    DISTRICT 02
2    DISTRICT 03
3    DISTRICT 04
4    DISTRICT 05
Name: District, dtype: object
```

Using astype gives the below error, how can this be done ?

```
dsAttendEnroll.District = dsAttendEnroll.District.map(lambda x: x[-2:]).astype(int)
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'LS'

Comment: that means your data has something that ends with `LS`...

Comment: I think you first need to decide what you want to do with the `LS` data.  Do you want to discard it or split it into a separate column (as suggested below)?  Is `LS` valid or invalid?

Comment: Thanks filtering out the incorrect data solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with selecting second lists by `str[1]` with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), where is parameter `errors='coerce'` - it convert not numeric values to `NaN`:

```
print (df)
      District
0  DISTRICT 01
1  DISTRICT 02
2  DISTRICT 03
3  DISTRICT 04
4  DISTRICT 05
5  DISTRICT LS

print (df.District.str.split().str[1])
0    01
1    02
2    03
3    04
4    05
5    LS
Name: District, dtype: object

print (pd.to_numeric(df.District.str.split().str[1], errors='coerce'))
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    NaN
Name: District, dtype: float64
```

Another solution with slice 2 last chars:

```
print (df.District.str[-2:])
0    01
1    02
2    03
3    04
4    05
5    LS
Name: District, dtype: object

print (pd.to_numeric(df.District.str[-2:], errors='coerce'))
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    NaN
Name: District, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I add another solution, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
dsAttendEnroll.District=pd.to_numeric(dsAttendEnroll.District)
dsAttendEnroll.District=dsAttendEnroll.District.astype(int)
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).